# Range from to in array with key and value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have task where customer pick time range but for different time there is different price, i have created 2 select fields with options of the time:

```
From time
<select>
  <option value="1">22:00</option>
  <option value="2">23:00</option>
  <option value="3">00:00</option>
  <option value="4">01:00</option>
</select>
etc...
```

```
to time
<select>
  <option value="5">04:00</option>
  <option value="6">05:00</option>
  <option value="7">06:00</option>
  <option value="8">07:00</option>
</select>
etc...
```

Then i created array where i set key to match option value.

```
var prices = {1: 100, 2: 125, 3: 125, 4: 150, 5: 150, };
```

Now the problem is how i can return range of selected dates.

Lets say i pick from 22:00h to 04:00h on select picker now how to filer array to get all keys from 1 - 5 and then get all values add to final price.

```
  for (var cost in prices) {
      sum += prices[cost];
  }
  console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the values of the `select` elements are all incremental integers, change `prices` to an array and `slice()` it by the indexes held in the values of the `select`, something like this:

```js
var prices = [100, 125, 125, 150, 150, 175, 175];
var $from = $('#from');
var $to = $('#to');

$('select').on('change', function() {
  var availablePrices = prices.slice($from.val() - 1, $to.val() - 1);
  console.log(availablePrices);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
From time
<select id="from">
  <option value="1">22:00</option>
  <option value="2">23:00</option>
  <option value="3">00:00</option>
  <option value="4">01:00</option>
</select>

to time
<select id="to">
  <option value="5">04:00</option>
  <option value="6">05:00</option>
  <option value="7">06:00</option>
  <option value="8">07:00</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$('select.from,select.to').change(function() {
  var fromval = $('select.from').val();
  var toval = $('select.to').val();
  var total= 0;

  for (var i = fromval; i <= toval; i++) {
    total = total + (+prices[i]);
  }
});
```

Please note I've added a class to each of your `select`

**Demo**

```js
var prices = {
  1: 100,
  2: 125,
  3: 125,
  4: 150,
  5: 150
};

$('select.from,select.to').change(function() {
  var fromval = $('select.from').val();
  var toval = $('select.to').val();
  var total= 0;

  for (var i = fromval; i <= toval; i++) {
    total = total + (+prices[i]);
  }
  
  console.log(total)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="from">
  <option value="1">22:00</option>
  <option value="2">23:00</option>
  <option value="3">00:00</option>
  <option value="4">01:00</option>
</select>
<select class="to">
  <option value="5">04:00</option>
  <option value="6">05:00</option>
  <option value="7">06:00</option>
  <option value="8">07:00</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sumSalaries(salaries) {

  let sum = 0;
  for (let salary of Object.values(salaries)) {
    sum += salary;
  }

  return sum; // 650
}

let salaries = {
  "John": 100,
  "Pete": 300,
  "Mary": 250
};

alert( sumSalaries(salaries) ); // 650
```